# using a HD images for iphone 3.x

Tags: iphone, ios

HI there
My project's images are designed for iphone4, which are, if i am not mistaken double the size of the iphone3 image.
May be i got the whole concept wrong

Is it true;

```
iPhone4 needs;for a whole screen image; a width of 640 while iphone3 uses only 320?   
Or is it just a high resolution, meaning same size (320) with more resolution?    
Do i need to have 2 versions of the images? How can i load different images/resources based on the IOS version?
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to worry about it the actual numbers or choosing which image should be displayed. You do need to provide two image versions to have it handled automatically:

Supposing full-screen images,

```
image.png - 480x320
image@2x.png - 960x640
```

When you do something like `[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]` - where `image.png` is a resource in your project - the system will choose the image with @2x as shown in preference to the normal image when you are on a device with a retina display. It will choose the smaller image for the smaller screen. In either case you request `"image.png"` NOT `"image@2x.png"` - the system takes care of it for you.

There is a little bit of trickery going on - you do treat the device as having 320 width and 480 height no matter which device you are on, this lets you target iPhone 3 and iPhone 4 without having lots of special case code. It is worth checking out the new documentation to see where the new `scale` value is used, where you need to be aware of the actual dimension.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for the tip - I was wondering, woudl'nt that bloat the app? carrying 2 versions of each image?

Comment: I guess it would. But if you target the larger display you are going to have those large images anyway, and your baggage is only 25% (a half-width, half-height image is 1/4 the pixels).

Comment: hey adam, just one question - if i have an image that is created programatically and if i assign 1.png to it with a width 320; if there is an image 1@2x.png with the width 620 - how will it load? I can try it and find out, but just curious if there is something else that i need to know

Comment: On an iPhone 4 it will load the 1@2x.png version, but you still treat it as if it were 320 pixels wide. The higher resolution is just something you don't have to care about.